# How to count features within a radius distance?

Tags: qgis, buffer, count, radius

I use QGIS and I have building polygons like this:

[image]

and I would like to calculate the number of polygons within a certain radius (100m for example) for each building to evaluate how dense is the area where the building is located.
So the number of buildings "near by" would be a new field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Field calculator with this expression:

```
array_length(
    overlay_nearest(
        @layer, 
        $id,
        max_distance:=100,
        limit:=100  -- change this value if you expect more then 100 buildings to fall within the max. distance
    )
)
```

*Result shown as label for each buliding - one of the buildings with red outlined 100m buffer - this building has 62 neighbors within 100 m:*

[image]